# Play 2.4.1, PlayEbean not found

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, ebean

After updating my Java project from 2.2 to 2.4, I followed the instructions on the Migration page, but am getting that error, saying the value PlayEbean was not found.

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell I only have to add that one line to the plugins.sbt file and it should work, right?

EDIT: I tried 2.4.2, exact same problem occured.

For clarity's sake: there is no build.sbt file. Only a Build.scala file and a BuildKeys.scala and BuildPlugin.scala file. Though those last 2 have no relation to this problem.

The files:

project/Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

import play.sbt.PlayImport._
import PlayKeys._

object BuildSettings {
    val appVersion        = "0.1"
    val buildScalaVersion = "2.11.7"

    val buildSettings = Seq (
        version      := appVersion,
        scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion
    )
}

object Resolvers {
    val typeSafeRepo = "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
    val localRepo = "Local Maven Repositor" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
    val bintrayRepo = "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
    val sbtRepo = "Public SBT repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"

    val myResolvers = Seq (
        typeSafeRepo,
        localRepo,
        bintrayRepo,
        sbtRepo
    )
}

object Dependencies {
        val mindrot = "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
        val libThrift = "org.apache.thrift" % "libthrift" % "0.9.2"
        val commonsLang3 = "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.4"
        val commonsExec = "org.apache.commons" % "commons-exec" % "1.3"
        val guava = "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "18.0"
        val log4j = "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.3"
        val jacksonDataType = "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype" % "jackson-datatype-joda" % "2.5.3"
        val jacksonDataformat = "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-xml" % "2.5.3"
        val postgresql = "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1103.jdbc41"

        val myDeps = Seq(
            // Part of play
            javaCore,
            javaJdbc,
            javaWs,
            cache,

            // User defined
            mindrot,
            libThrift,
            commonsLang3,
            commonsExec,
            guava,
            log4j,
            jacksonDataType,
            jacksonDataformat,
            postgresql
        )
}

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
    import Resolvers._
    import Dependencies._
    import BuildSettings._

    val appName = "sandbox"

    val main = Project(
            appName, 
            file("."),
            settings = buildSettings ++ Seq (resolvers := myResolvers, libraryDependencies := myDeps)
        )
    .enablePlugins(play.PlayJava, PlayEbean)
    .settings(jacoco.settings: _*)
    .settings(parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false)
    .settings(javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Xmx512M"))
    .settings(javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-XX:MaxPermSize=512M"))
}
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.1")

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Local Maven Repositor" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository",
  "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
  "Public SBT repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.puppycrawl.tools" % "checkstyle" % "6.8",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-java-ws" % "2.4.1",
  "org.jacoco" % "org.jacoco.core" % "0.7.1.201405082137" artifacts(Artifact("org.jacoco.core", "jar", "jar")),
  "org.jacoco" % "org.jacoco.report" % "0.7.1.201405082137" artifacts(Artifact("org.jacoco.report", "jar", "jar"))
)

// Plugin for code coverage
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.6")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(SbtEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

I have tried adding javaEbean to the myDeps variable, output remains the same.

Also, contrary to all the examples and tutorials, if I want to enable PlayJava, I have to do it via play.PlayJava. What is up with that?

Comment: Where is your `enablePlugins(SbtEbean)`?

Comment: @bjfletcher Adding that gives me the same problem: "not found: value SbtEbean"

Comment: Can you add `build.sbt` content to your question please?

Comment: @bjfletcher After some more searching, I found that they simply renamed SbtEbean to PlayEbean during the 2.4 development: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commit/71254f66c545ed0ad0d49a279ff38a09b14f57ea

Comment: @bjfletcher There is no build.sbt, only a Build.scala file.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed your `Build.scala` there. That's great. :) Is it now working ok?

Comment: @bjfletcher No, it is still giving me the same error. It keeps claiming PlayEbean cannot be found. I tried adding more precise resolvers, tried switching scala versions but it keeps saying that. Am I missing am import or something?

Comment: Try changing: `.enablePlugins(play.PlayJava, PlayEbean)` to `.enablePlugins(play.PlayJava, play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For the error: `not found: value PlayEbean`, you must `import play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean` in `Build.scala`,
2. Then you will have a not-found error for `jacoco`, you must `import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin.jacoco`,
3. After that a `NoClassDefFoundError`, there you must upgrade SBT to `0.13.8` in `project/build.properties`,
4. Finally the postgresql dependency is incorrect and doesn't resolve.

The SBT part should work, in my case it fail later because I don't have eBeans in project.

Patch version:

```
diff a/project/Build.scala b/project/Build.scala
--- a/project/Build.scala
+++ b/project/Build.scala
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
+import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.JacocoPlugin.jacoco
+import play.ebean.sbt.PlayEbean
 import play.sbt.PlayImport._
 import sbt.Keys._
 import sbt._
@@ -35,7 +37,7 @@
    val log4j = "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.3"
    val jacksonDataType = "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype" % "jackson-datatype-joda" % "2.5.3"
    val jacksonDataformat = "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-xml" % "2.5.3"
-   val postgresql = "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1103.jdbc41"
+   val postgresql = "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1103-jdbc41"

    val myDeps = Seq(
        // Part of play
diff a/project/build.properties b/project/build.properties
--- a/project/build.properties
+++ b/project/build.properties
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-sbt.version=0.13.5
+sbt.version=0.13.8
```

EDIT: How did I end up with this: the latest versions of Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA allow better editing of SBT configs (than previously), but (for now) one need to make the SBT project build a first time to import it (i.e. commenting suspicious lines). Once the project is imported, one can use autocompletion, auto-import and other joys. I hope it will be usefull with `crossScalaVersions`. About that, keep in mind that Play 2.4 is Java 8+ only and Scala 2.10 doesn't support fully Java 8. (First section of the "Play 2.4 Migration Guide")

Comment: Well, it worked. It's correctly resolving PlayEbean now. I'm still kinda miffed that I couldn't find this myself somewhere. Now I'm dealing with crossScalaVersions. Thanks for the help with this.

Comment: @KdgDev I just added a simple howto is hope it will help you for future developments

Comment: Thanks. I use eclipse myself and that apparently requires installing the eclipseIDE plugin. I'll have a look at InteliJ tonight.

Comment: Woops, forgot to award the bounty. Didn't know you had to click the little icon. I thought accepting the answer was enough.

Comment: Wait... isn't this supposed to be an easier build system?